# Where do I need to place the if statement?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

I need to print this output:

```
Guess the price and win the prize!
Enter your guess:46000
Too high!
Enter your guess:45000
Too high!
Enter your guess:44000
Too high!
Enter your guess:43000
Too high!
Enter your guess:42000
Too low!
Enter your guess:42500
Too many guesses!
```

This is my code:

```
guess_count = 0
car_price = 42500 

print("Guess the price and win the prize!")
while guess_count <= 5:
   guess_count = guess_count + 1
   guess = int(input("Enter your guess:"))

  if guess == car_price:
    print("You won the car!")
  elif guess < car_price:
    print("Too low!")
  elif guess > car_price:
    print("Too high!")
  if guess_count > 5:
    print("Too many guesses!")
```

If I input 5 guesses, the code above gives me an output like this:

```
  Too low!
  Too many guesses!
```

When a user inputs more than 5 guesses, I just want to print:

```
  Too many guesses!
```

What do I need to fix?

Comment: some of the indentation seems wrong....

Comment: If you see the printout in the wrong order, change the order of printouts.

Answer (score 2):

the code checks the number guessed and then checks how many guesses have been made and if it is over 5 it prints `Too many guesses!`

try either printing the `Too many guesses!` text either after the while loop or make it break out of the loop when too many guesses have been made

```py
guess_count = 0
car_price = 42500 

print("Guess the price and win the prize!")
while True:
    guess_count = guess_count + 1
    guess = int(input("Enter your guess:"))

    if guess_count <= 5:
        print("Too many guesses!")
        break
    if guess == car_price:
        print("You won the car!")
        break
    elif guess < car_price:
        print("Too low!")
    elif guess > car_price:
        print("Too high!")
```

note in the above code I have changed it to be an infinite loop which breaks out after too many guesses and skips over the too low or high text.

Comment: It's `>=` and not `=>`. That is a syntax error. Also, This will keep asking for guesses even after receiving the correct guess.

Comment: one second i will fix it

Answer (score 0):

In the other answer, if the user enters the CORRECT price..it will still keep asking for guesses which should not happen. No need for infinite loop, this is the right way.Note:- `range(n)` goes from `0` to `n-1`

```
correct = 42500
print("Enter correct amount and win")
for i in range(6):
    guess = int(input("Enter your guess :"))
    if i > 4:
        print("Too many guesses!")
        break
    if guess == correct:
        print("You won")
        break
    elif guess < correct:
        print("Too low")
    else:
        print("Too high!")
```